# io.to(room).emit(); isnt working, not getting any response in the frontend

Tags: sockets, socket.io, mern

I am successfully joining rooms that the user have in its database when ever the user successfully log in. I am debugging the room sockets and i am getting 2 sockets in the room but whenever i am emitting a call to room using io.to(roomid) it isnt giving any response in the frontend socket.

backend code

import app from "./app.js";

```
import { connectDB } from "./config/database.js";
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import http from "http";
import { catchAsyncError } from "./middleware/catchAsyncError.js";
import { Message } from "./models/Message.js";
import { Conversation } from "./models/Conversation.js";

connectDB();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("<h1>Working Fine</h1>");
});

app.route("/users").get((req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    users: [],
    success: false,
  });
});

const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on PORT: ${process.env.PORT}`);
});

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

const onlineUserList = new Map();

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("Connected to socketio");
  console.log(socket.id);

  //user joined app
  socket.on("user-joined", async (userInfo) => {
    if (!userInfo) return;
    const userId = userInfo.userInfo._id;
    onlineUserList.set(socket.id, userId);

    const conversationIds = await Conversation.find(
      { users: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } },
      { _id: 1 }
    );

    // socket.join("room1");
    if (conversationIds.length != 0)
      conversationIds.map((conversation) => {
        socket.join(conversation._id.toString());
      });
  });

  //user disconnected
  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    onlineUserList.delete(socket.id);
    const currentId = onlineUserList.get(socket.id);
    io.emit("userDisconnected", currentId);
  });

  //join new room
  socket.on("join_room", (conversationId) => {
    socket.join(conversationId);
  });

  // user typing
  socket.on("typing", (conversationId) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(conversationId).emit("typing");
  });

  // user stopped typing
  socket.on("stop-tping", (conversationId) => {
    socket.broadcast.to(conversationId).emit("stop-typing");
  });

  //new message
  socket.on(
    "new-message",
    catchAsyncError(async (message, conversationId, senderId) => {
      // const newMessage = await Message.create({
      //   conversationId: conversationId,
      //   senderId: senderId,
      //   message,
      // });

      // const conversation = await Conversation.findOne({ _id: conversationId });

      // conversation.updatedAt = Date.now();
      // await conversation.save();
      // conversation.lastMessage = newMessage._id;
      // await conversation.save();

      // socket.emit("message-sent", {
      //   messageId: newMessage._id,
      //   status: "sent",
      // });

      // io.to("room1").emit("message-received", newMessage);

      // console.log(typeof conversationId);
      // console.log(conversationId);

      // const socketsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(conversationId);

      // console.log("Sockets in room:", socketsInRoom);
      // io.to(conversationId).emit("message-received");
      // socket.to(conversationId).emit("message-received");

      io.to(conversationId).emit("message-received");
    })
  );

  //message read
  socket.on(
    "message-read",
    catchAsyncError(async (messageId) => {})
  );
});
```

**frontend code**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "../components/header/Header";
import classes from "./Message.module.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";
import SentimentSatisfiedAltIcon from "@mui/icons-material/SentimentSatisfiedAlt";
import ChatPerson from "../components/item/ChatPerson";
import { url } from "../store/store";
import socket from "../store/socket";

function Message() {
  const userInfo = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const chatPerson = useSelector((state) => state.chatperson);

  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const [loading1, setLoading1] = useState(true);
  const [loading2, setLoading2] = useState(true);
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchConversations = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading1(true);
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:4000/api/conversations/${userInfo.userInfo._id}`,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        );
        setLoading1(false);
        console.log(data);
        let temp = [];
        if (data.conversations) {
          data.conversations.map((conversation) => {
            let currArray = conversation.users;
            if (currArray[0] != userInfo.userInfo._id) {
              temp.push([currArray[0], conversation._id]);
            } else {
              temp.push([currArray[1], conversation._id]);
            }
          });
        }

        setIds(temp);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading1(false);
        console.log("error in Message js");
        console.log(error);
      }
    };

    userInfo && fetchConversations();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMessages = async () => {
      setMessages([]);
      try {
        setLoading2(true);
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `${url}/messages/${chatPerson.conversationId}`,
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-type": "application/json",
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        );
        setLoading2(false);
        setMessages(data.messages);
      } catch (error) {
        setLoading2(false);
        console.log("Error in message.jsx 3");
      }
    };

    userInfo && chatPerson && chatPerson.conversationId && fetchMessages();
  }, [chatPerson]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("message-sent", (data) => {
      console.log(data.messageId, data.status);
    });
    socket.on("message-received", () => {
      // setMessages([...messages, newMessage]);
      console.log("message recieved");
    });
    socket.on("check", (data) => {
      console.log(data.value);
    });

    return () => {
      socket.off("message-sent");
      socket.off("user-joined");
      socket.emit("disconnected");
    };
  }, []);

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if (
      chatPerson &&
      chatPerson.conversationId &&
      userInfo &&
      userInfo.userInfo
    ) {
      socket.emit(
        "new-message",
        message,
        chatPerson.conversationId,
        userInfo.userInfo._id
      );
    }
    setMessage("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.container2}>
          <div className={classes.leftContainer}>
            <div className={classes.heading1}>Messaging</div>
            <div className={classes.searchBar}>
              <SearchIcon sx={{ color: "gray", margin: "0 0 0 4px" }} />
              <input className={classes.searchInput} type="text" />
            </div>
            <div className={classes.chatsContainer}>
              {ids.length > 0 ? (
                ids.map((item, index) => (
                  <ChatPerson key={index} id={ids[index]} />
                ))
              ) : (
                <div>No conversation found</div>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={classes.rightContainer}>
            <div className={classes.infoBar}>
              <img className={classes.image} src="" alt="" />
              <div className={classes.name}>
                {chatPerson && chatPerson.chatPersonInfo
                  ? chatPerson.chatPersonInfo.username
                  : ""}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className={classes.chatContainer}>
              {loading2 && <div>..loading</div>}
              {!loading2 && messages.length === 0 ? (
                <div>No messages</div>
              ) : (
                messages.map((message, index) => {
                  if (
                    userInfo &&
                    userInfo.userInfo &&
                    message.senderId === userInfo.userInfo._id
                  ) {
                    return (
                      <div key={index} className={classes.myMessage}>
                        <div className={classes.text}>{message.message}</div>
                        <div className={classes.time}>{message.createdAt}</div>
                      </div>
                    );
                  }
                  return (
                    <div key={index} className={classes.notMyMessage}>
                      <div className={classes.text}>{message.message}</div>
                      <div className={classes.time}>{message.createdAt}</div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })
              )}
            </div>
            <div className={classes.textContainer}>
              <SentimentSatisfiedAltIcon
                className={classes.icon}
                sx={{ fontSize: "34px", margin: "0 8px" }}
              />
              <textarea
                value={message}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setMessage(e.target.value);
                }}
                className={classes.textInputField}
                type="text"
              />
              <SendIcon
                className={classes.icon}
                onClick={sendMessage}
                sx={{ fontSize: "44px", margin: "0 16px" }}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Message;
```

i was expecting a response from the backend in the frontend but didnt get any